# Simulate an http error in when testing an angular interceptor

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a Angular HTTP interceptor that should track and untrack each http request and im writing tests for it, im stuck at writing a test for an http request with 404 status code. when i run the tests i see an uncaught error in the terminal which tells me that im not handling the error accordingly but i think that it is being handled. can you tell me where my miss is?

here is angular http interceptor

```
@Injectable()
export class TrafficInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private trafficService: TrafficService) {
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
        this.trafficService.trackRequest(request);
        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                this.trafficService.unTrackRequest(request);
                return throwError(error);
            }),
            finalize(() => {
                this.trafficService.unTrackRequest(request);
            })
        );
    }
}
```

and here are the tests

```
describe('TrafficInterceptor', () => {
    let interceptor: TrafficInterceptor;
    let trafficStateStore: TrafficStateStore;
    let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
    let http: HttpClient;

    const reqURL = '/somewebsite/foo';
    const httpMethods = [
        {method: 'get'},
        {method: 'delete'},
        {method: 'post'},
        {method: 'put'},
        {method: 'patch'}
    ];

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
            providers: [
                {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TrafficInterceptor, multi: true},
                TrafficInterceptor,
                TrafficStateStore,
                TrafficService
            ]
        });
        interceptor = TestBed.inject(TrafficInterceptor);
        trafficStateStore = TestBed.inject(TrafficStateStore);

        httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
        http = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        httpTestingController.verify();
    });

    it('should be created', () => {
        expect(interceptor).toBeTruthy();
    });

    httpMethods.forEach(({method}) => {
        it(`should track and untrack a successfull HTTP - ${method} metod`, () => {
            httpRequest(reqURL, method);
            const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(reqURL);

            expect(trafficStateStore.get('showPendingOverlay')).toBeTrue();
            expect(trafficStateStore.get('isRequestProcessing')).toBeTrue();

            req.flush({});

            expect(trafficStateStore.get('showPendingOverlay')).toBeFalse();
            expect(trafficStateStore.get('isRequestProcessing')).toBeFalse();
        });


        it(`should track and untrack a unsuccessfull HTTP - ${method} metod`, () => {
            httpRequest(reqURL, method);
            const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(reqURL);

            expect(trafficStateStore.get('showPendingOverlay')).toBeTrue();
            expect(trafficStateStore.get('isRequestProcessing')).toBeTrue();

            req.flush('', {status: 404, statusText: 'error'});

            expect(trafficStateStore.get('showPendingOverlay')).toBeFalse();
            expect(trafficStateStore.get('isRequestProcessing')).toBeFalse();
        });
    });

    function httpRequest(url: string, method: string, data?: Record<string, boolean>, params: Record<string, boolean> = {}): void {
        if (data) {
            http[method](url, data, {params}).subscribe();
        } else {
            http[method](url, {params}).subscribe();
        }
    }
});
```

the error in the terminal is Uncaught [object Object]

Comment: Where in your test, is it failing ?

Comment: the test is failing when an unsuccessful status code is provided. basically it reaches the catchError observable and throws an uncaught error. here is what i see in the terminal https://ibb.co/sQjpndv

Answer (score 2):

All that i needed to do is pass to the subscribe an error callback so that the test knows how to process the error

```
it(`should track and untrack a unsuccessfull HTTP - ${method} method`, (done: DoneFn) => {
            http[method](reqURL).subscribe({
                error: (err) => {
                    expect(err.status).toEqual(404);
                    done();
                }
            });
            const req: TestRequest = httpTestingController.expectOne(reqURL);

            expect(something).toBeTrue();
            expect(something).toBeTrue();

            req.flush('', {status: 404, statusText: 'error'});

            expect(something).toBeFalse();
            expect(something).toBeFalse();
        });
```